# Use command prompt to change date and time

Tags: windows-10, command-line, cmd.exe

Recently I worked a lot with the command prompt. Now I want to know if it is possible to change the date and time of the system (Windows 10), only with the command prompt and how I can do it.

Comment: Have you tried with the `date` and `time` commands?

Comment: No , i haven't tried a lot , because i want to be sure about what i do

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Open a command prompt window. I don't think it requires administrative privileges, but if it says Access Denied after you attempt to change the date/time, close the window and reopen with administrative privileges.

With the command prompt open, type `date` and press enter. It asks you to enter a new date. Do so and press enter again.

Now type `time` and press enter. It asks you to enter a new time.

If at either of these prompts, you press enter without entering a new date/time, the date/time will not be changed.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Identify the date format

Check the date format before you update, by typing the following in cmd prompt

```
date
```

In the output, you will see the date along with option to enter new date which shows the format as follows:

```
The current date is: Sat 07/31/2021
Enter the new date: (mm-dd-yy)
```

Step 2: Update Date

Now, it is evident that my pc has `mm-dd-yy` so in order to update date,  you can put the following or the format that matches the date format on your PC, in a batch file or run via cmd prompt to set to date having format `mm/dd/yyyy`

```
date 04/14/2020
```

Comment: -1 because the date format will be different depending on your locale. For example, I would have to type `date dd-mm-yyyy`, others may have to type date `yyyy/mm/dd`

Comment: @LPChip sounds like you think so just because you think it's logical :) But MS documentation disagrees, the format is always month-day-year, separated by hyphens, slashes or dots. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/date

Comment: @FedericoRazzoli No its not. I speak of experience. You linked to documentation with the en-us language, yes then it is using the english notation. But if you refer to the same documentation in dutch locale: nl-nl, you'll see it is dd-mm-yyyy.

Comment: @LPChip Err, no, you made me check for nothing :) And it's not just English and Dutch, but Italian and Spanish. Also, documentation is written for all users not for a specific locale. https://docs.microsoft.com/nl-nl/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/date

Comment: @FedericoRazzoli Okay, so apparently the tech documentation on microsoft.com is incorrect. On my local system which is also dutch, if I type `date` or `date /t` it both tells me that the date is in format dd-mm-yy and that I have to enter it as such. I even tried to enter date 01/31/2020 as it is the only way to write januari 31st, 2020 and it complains it is an invalid date. I've provided a picture in my answer.

Comment: @LPChip Can you report this documentation bug? Bug reports help keep the quality of products and documentation high. Though I'm not sure how/if MS allows to report bugs, since I'm not a user of their products.

Comment: Updated the answer with detail. Hope this helps