# Sync date & time from command line / batch file

Tags: date

Windows 11 (not on a domain): the setting to sync with time server is turned off.  The goal is to be able to quickly execute a batch file to toggle between the current date and a specific date from the command line

To [set the date from the command line](https://superuser.com/a/1539857/45436):

```
date mm/dd/yyyy

date 04/14/2020
```

Is there a similar command to sync the date with a "time" server?

UPDATE:

https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/6410-synchronize-clock-internet-time-server-windows-10-a.html

```
w32tm /resync
```

- w32tm worked in Win10
- w32tm in Win11 returns an error: "The service has not been started"

Comment: It would be vastly easier just to tun the service ON to enable time sync

Comment: I would like to avoid the settings GUI.   The goal is to be able to quickly execute a batch file to toggle between the current date and a specific date from the command line

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.  Setting an arbitrary time in Windows can disable other things (Iinternet)

Comment: Yes. This is true, however, this is not a problem because this computer is for experiments only and is not the “daily driver”

Comment: Try:   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/set-date?view=powershell-7.3

Comment: See also https://serverfault.com/questions/356259/how-to-temporarily-stop-time-syncing-with-domain-controller . Note that Registry changes might *not* take place immediately, and might require reboot... so using the Settings dialog could be more efficient, in that case.